# CompositeAPI: Template reference of HTML Object - TS2339 + TS2533 (.value returns Proxy Object)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am struggling with referencing an element in VueJS 3, CompositeAPI. My implementation looks like following:

```
<div ref="myIdentifier"></div>

setup() {
  const myIdentifier = ref(null);
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log(myIdentifier.value); // returns a Proxy object. WHY??? it should return the Element object
    console.log(myIdentifier.value.$el); // returns the Element object
    // !!! to mention here:
    // TypeScript complains about TS2339 Property ... does not exist on type 'never'
    // if escaped myIdentifier.value?.$el, if, even myIdentifier.value!.$el: TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'

  });

  return {};
},
```

Assumably I do something wrong here. My goal is to have the Element reference (HTML) available. I doubt that in order to access this element, so much escaping is needed here or that it is so difficult to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't "spam" the title with stuff that should be a `tag`. The title should give a short summary of the actual problem.

Comment: Changed accordingly, it was not my intention to spam.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, because you are using TypeScript, specify what `myIdentifier` really is.

```
const myIdentifier = ref<HTMLDivElement>(); // Ref<HTMLDivElement | undefined>
```

Now, to access the referenced HTML element you do

```
onMounted(() => {
      console.log(myIdentifier.value) // HTMLDivElement | undefined
      console.log(myIdentifier.value?.style) // CSSStyleDeclaration | undefined
});
```

Of course you can't safely access properties of `myIdentifier.value`, so a question mark is needed `myIdentifier.value?.style`, because it might be undefined. When? For example if you don't add `ref="myIdentifier"` to your html element.

But in your case it's always undefined, because you don't return your template ref `myIdentifier` from the `setup()` function

```
setup() {
  const myIdentifier = ref<HTMLDivElement>();

  onMounted(() => { /* do sth with myIdentifier */ });

  return { 
    myIdentifier 
  };
},
```

And the problem is solved.

**Edit:** Now I will also answer your other question

> console.log(taskSliderCard.value); // returns a Proxy object. WHY???

Not 100% sure what `taskSliderCard` is, but it's most likely a reference to Vue component (`<TaskSliderCard ref="taskSliderCard" />`). In this case, `taskSliderCard.value` returns component instance, rather than HTML element.

Since it doesn't return HTML element, you will also need to specify other type for your `taskSliderCard` ref inside `setup()`, for example this way:

```
import { TaskSliderCard } from 'your-ui-library'
...
setup() {
    // Get the type of TaskSliderCard component
    // So TypeScript compiler knows its properties
    const taskSliderCard = ref<InstanceType<typeof TaskSliderCard>>();

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(taskSliderCard.value?.$el) // HTMLElement | Undefined

    });

    return { taskSliderCard};
},
```

Comment: Sorry, as I copied the text, I overlooked the taskSliderCard variable. Changed accordingly.

Comment: It seems that I am really out of luck. I try various alternatives and still receive myIdentifier.value -> "Proxy". Only while calling myIdentifier.value.$el the HTMLElement is returned but TS is complaining "TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.". While doing this, I changed the definition into: const myIdentifier = ref<HTMLDivElement>(); Like:
setup() {
  const myIdentifier = ref<HTMLDivElement>();
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log(myIdentifier.value.$el); // Proxy {…}[[Handler]]: Object[[Target]]: Object[[IsRevoked]]: false
  };
  return {
    myIdentifier
  };
}

Comment: Do you really have `<div ref="myIdentifier"></div>` inside `<template>`, or it's something else?

Comment: yes, it is a ionic wrapper around it. This is really a pitfall. A similar situation is described here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-refs-and-the-vue-3-composition-api/200783/12.
I ended up wrapping the parent - <ion-content> into a div and this gets the ref="myIdentifier". It is a extra necessary step but it helped to make the reference work like a charm. !!! Thank you for your support!!!